# How does one prove that $\operatorname{Log}(1-z^{2})=\operatorname{Log}(1-z)+\operatorname{Log}(1+z)$ when $|z|\lt 1?$

Tags: complex-numbers

This is Exercise EP$20$ from Fernandez and Bernardes's book *Introdução às Funções de uma Variável Complexa*.

Check that $\operatorname{Log}(1-z^{2})=\operatorname{Log}(1-z)+\operatorname{Log}(1+z)$ when $|z|\lt 1$. What one can say about $\operatorname{Log}\frac{(1-z)}{(1+z)}?$

I'll be honest with you. I don't know how to use $|z|\lt 1$. Let me show what I did so far $\operatorname{Log}(1-z^{2})=\ln|1-z^{2}|+i\operatorname{Arg}(1-z^{2})=\ln|1-z|+\ln|1+z|+i\operatorname{Arg}(1-z^{2})$. Should I use the hypothesis  $|z|\lt 1$ to prove that $\operatorname{Arg}(1-z^{2})=\operatorname{Arg}(1-z)+\operatorname{Arg}(1+z)?$

**EDIT:** Where $\operatorname{Log(z)}=\ln|z|+i\operatorname{Arg(z)}$ and $\operatorname{Arg(z)}$ is the unique argument of $z$ that belongs to $(-\pi,\pi].$

Comment: What's your definition of $\text{Log}$? A power series? Then you need $|z| < 1$ to ensure absolute convergence.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: $\operatorname{Log(z)}=\ln|z|+i\operatorname{Arg(z)}$.

Comment: And what's your definition of $\text{Arg}$?

Comment: It is the unique argument of $z$ that belongs to $(-\pi,\pi]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume they are using $\text{Arg}$ for the principal branch of the argument, i.e.  $-\pi < \text{Arg}\ w \le \pi$.  You'll have to
check that $-\pi < \text{Arg}\ (1-z) + \text{Arg}\ (1+z) \le \pi$.  Hint: if $1-z$ is in the upper half plane, $1+z$ is in the lower, and vice versa.  The result is actually true for all $z \ne \pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Both sides of the equations are holomorphic functions in the unit disk, and they are equal on the interval $(-1,1)$. By the identity theorem, they must be equal everywhere in the disk.

Comment: Perfect job. Simple and elegant.